# Git merge directories that have become separated

Tags: linux, git, symfony, merge, tortoisegit

Not quite sure how to explain this clearly, but here goes.

Due to a bug in Tortoise-git, we've ended with a situation like this;

All our code should be under a directory structure like this (this is Symfony2 project);

```
src/XYZ/OurExitingBundle
src/XYZ/AnotherExcitingBundle
```

but, due (we think) to the bug in Tortoise-git, when we pull the code onto a linux box, we've got;

```
src/XYZ/OurExcitingBundle
src/XYZ/AnotherExcitingBundle
src/xyz/ourexcitingbundle
src/xyz/anotherexcitingbundle
```

(i.e. the actual directories, plus a lowercase equivalent). The files making our project seem to be split randomly between the CamelCase and the lowercase directories.

As we are developing on Windows machines, this does not matter whilst coding, but when the code is pushed to our linux server, everything falls over, as files are not where they are supposed to be, or a file exists in the CamelCase directory, but a newer version is in the lowercase directory.

So, my question is, is there a way to "merge" all the files in the lowercase directories into their equivalents in the CamelCase directories, ending up with all the latest code in just the CamelCase directories?

Many thanks in advance for all help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two things to do here.  The easiest of which it to make sure each client on windows has

```
core.ignorecase = true
```

set on each of their repositories. This means that git will ignore any differences in case locally and should use the same case as used in the local repository.

Secondly all the paths that are have incorrect spacing will need to be changed in the repository.  This has the side effect that the team would have to pull this new version of the history.  The `filter-branch` command is often used for this type of task. This would be something like:

```
git filter-branch --tree-filter 'test -d src/xyz && for f in `git ls-files src/xyz`; do git mv "$f" src/XYZ; done'
```

There have also been changes to Tortoise Git to improve support for handling case sensitivity:

- https://tortoisegit.org/issue/830
- https://tortoisegit.org/issue/548

So it's also worth checking the version you are using.

Comment: Thank you. We tried everything you suggested, but the only thing that worked was manually moving everything from the incorrectly-cased directories into the right ones. The problem has no re-occurred, so I suspect it was down to using an old version of Tortoise.